# Is "atestat" a synonym for "certificate"?

Tags: word-meaning, synonyms, false-friend

I would like to know whether the word "atestat" exists in the English language or if it is just a bad usage from speakers in my country due to the similarity with a word in our native language.

It is supposed to be a synonym for "certificate", but I couldn't find it in any dictionary (apart from Google Translate if it may be regarded as a dictionary, but I don't really trust this source in general).

Comment: Dictionaries show whether words exist in English. **Atestat** sounds like Catalan to me for a report. Don't you know the source language?? What is your country?

Answer (score 5):

If I search for the English equivalent of the *noun* ["attestato"](https://www.wordreference.com/iten/attestato) I find the following translations

**certificate**
**written declaration**

- At the end of the course we were given an attendance certificate.

The word “atestat” is not English, and no English native speaker, unfamiliar with Italian or Romanian, would have the slightest idea what the speaker intended (= meant).

Comment: There is also the word "attestation", which is a formal statement that something is true. The verbs "certify" and "attest" are really close.

Comment: @Gustavson so, are you saying the noun "the attest" or "the atestate" exists in English because the verb "to attest" does? My answer focuses on the equivalent noun form and whether "atestat" is an English word, it is not.

Comment: I would be able to guess the meaning from context, but it's definitely not English.

Comment: (@Gustavson) no; 'attest' is only a verb. The noun 'attestation' is fairly common in US business as part of [Statement on Standards for Attestation Engagements (SSAE) 16-now-18](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSAE_16), the auditing standard used for some service providers.

Comment: It can be Catalan,too. No guarantee this is Italian or Romanian.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I never said "attest" was a noun.